# Add Class to <a> based on the level in a nested list

Tags: jquery, list, nested, addclass

```
<div id="ContentLeftNav"><ul class="menu">
    <li class=""><a href="#" class=" ">Test Page</a></li>
    <li class=""><a href="#" class=" ">Test Page</a></li>
    <li class=""><a href="#" class="expandNav ">Test Page</a>
            <ul class="submenu">
                    <li class=""><a href="#" class=" ">Test Page</a></li>
                    <li class=""><a href="#" class="expandNav2">Test Page</a>
                         <ul class="submenu2">
                            <li class=""><a href="#" class=" ">Test Page</a></li>
                            <li class=""><a href="#" class=" ">Test Page</a></li>
                         </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li class=""><a href="#" class=" ">Test Page</a></li>
                    <li class="last"><a href="#" class=" ">Test Page</a></li>
             </ul>
     </li>
    <li class=""><a href="#" class=" ">Test Page</a></li>
    <li class=""><a href="#" class="expandNav">Test Page</a>
            <ul class="submenu">
                    <li class=""><a href="#" class="expand2">Test Page</a></li>
                        <ul class="submenu2">
                            <li class=""><a href="#" class=" ">Test Page</a></li>
                            <li class=""><a href="#" class=" ">Test Page</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    <li class=""><a href="#" class=" ">Test Page</a></li>
            </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="last"><a href="#" class=" ">Test Page</a></li></ul></div>
```

I'm looking for jQuery script that will add a class to the `<a>` if it has a `<ul>` based on the level it is in the unordered list. So all `<a>` + `<ul>` Level 1 would be "expandNav1" and level 2 would be "expandNav2" and level 3 would be "expandNav3" and so on. The script I'm using now is not working that way. It adds a new number on every `<a>` with `<ul>`.

```
$('#ContentLeftNav ul').each(function() {
$(this).find('li:has(ul)').each(function(i) {
    $(this).find('a').addClass('expandNav' + (i+1));
});});
```

How can I change it to look for level it is in?

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `.parents()` function tied with `.length` on each link:

```
$('#ContentLeftNav a').each(function() {
    $(this).addClass('expandNav' + $(this).parents('#ContentLeftNav ul').length);
});
```

But if you're just using this for styling, you might want to consider using plain CSS, and skipping the JS altogether:

```
#ContentLeftNav ul a {...}
#ContentLeftNav ul ul a {...}
#ContentLeftNav ul ul ul a {...}
/* And so forth. */
```

**Update:**

I think I misunderstood the original question.  If you're using the `.expandNav` class to mark links that are used to show/hide more detailed info (an expandable tree view, if you will), and you only want the links that directly precede `<ul>`s to get the class, then you actually want something more like this:

```
$('#ContentLeftNav a + ul').each(function() {
    // $(this) is the ul, so $(this).prev() is the a:
    $(this).prev().addClass('expandNav' + $(this).parents('#ContentLeftNav ul').length);
});
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: The class is not being used to style the `<a>`. The expandNav class is being used by another script. The script doesn't add the class it expects you to add it to all the `<a>` with `<ul>`.  I was trying to have this script do all the work for me.

Comment: @Ashlee  Ah - I may have misunderstood.  The old version would have given the class to _all_ the `<a>`s, but you only want them on the `<a>`s that come before `<ul>`s...  I've updated my answer - take a look.  Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with a recursive (= calls itself) function:

```
/* 
    Recursive loop though UL list
*/

function loopDown($obj, x){

    // Store our current jquery objects
    var $sub = $obj.children('ul').children('li:has(ul)');
    var $a = $sub.children('a');

    // Test is we need to continue loop - if not the function ends itself.
    if ($sub){

        if (x !== 0) {
            $a.addClass('expandNav'+x);
        }

        else {
            $a.addClass('expandNav');
        }

        //Incriment counter
        x++;

        $sub.each(function(){
            // Call the function one down the line...
            loopDown($(this), x);           
        });         
    }       
}

// Run our function, pass it the jQuery object and a starting counter.
loopDown($('#ContentLeftNav'), 0);
```